# Prevent extruded/poked vertices from inheriting vertex group they were extruded/poked from?

Tags: vertex-groups

Subject says it all.

1. Create icosphere
2. Assign all verts to vertex group.
3. Poke all faces.
4. I now want to select SOLELY the verts that were part of the pre-poked icosphere, and NOT select the newly poked verts.

It seems impossible. When I select my original vertex group, the poked verts are included even though I don't want them to be, and didn't manually assign them to the vertex group. Same problem happens with extrusion or applying subdivision surface.

Is there a secret "new verts don't inherit vertex group" setting I'm not aware of?

Comment: I was actually trying to replicate this Cinema4D tutorial in Blender:

https://player.vimeo.com/video/204725055?autoplay=1

It makes use of an "editor keeps my old selection" ability of C4D that doesn't seem easy to duplicate in Blender.

Comment: This is harder than it should be-- it would be nice if poke faces followed the standard of most other generative tools, that leave only newly created verts selected.  But using checker deselect->assign to v-group->poke->vertex weight edit with custom curve->clean (sigh) it is possible to end up with a v-group that contains only your poke verts.

Answer (score 0):

After 'poking' select one of the new vertices - <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and choose *Amount of Adjacent Faces* then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert selection. Create new vertex group if necessary.

Should probably add that the behavior is the same as parenting - meaning the children inherit the vertex group of their parents...

Comment: That WILL handle the specific case I described, but my gut feeling is it doesn't generalize to all possible cases of adding geometry :(

Comment: :) I think your gut feeling is correct.